# Memory Issue during compiling less with grunt

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, bower

i'm currently using bower + grunt to build my website.

dependencies in `bower.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.3",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.2",
    "admin-lte": "~2.0.0"
  },
```

dependecies in my `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-bower-concat": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.2",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0"
  },
```

I was using `AdminLTE 1.4.*` and all was fine. I updated to `AdminLTE 2.0.0` and when I try to compile my less file I receive this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I have my `base.less` file that include just `bootstrap` ad `Adminlte` stylesheets.
If I exclude some files from the imports of `adminlte.less` file (bootstrap variables and mixins and all the skins) it compiles with no error, but I need to import the skins too :)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this commenting out these lines in the AdminLTE.less:

```
@import "../bootstrap-less/mixins.less";
@import "../bootstrap-less/variables.less";
```

And did the same in the file of the skin I used:

```
/*
 * Skin: Blue
 * ----------
 */
//@import "../../bootstrap-less/mixins.less";
//@import "../../bootstrap-less/variables.less";
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't look like a good solution, since it's "just" commenting out code. How does your less file compile after commenting these lines?